# Xamarin ios - Error getting value of selected item from a dynamic UIAlertController

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a list which creates years and am using this list to dynamically create a UIAlertController.

The user clicks on a button from a row in a tableview, which launches the UIAlertController and the user can select a year.

My challenge is:

1. Each time I select a year from the controller,it selects the cancel button.

What is the correct way of getting the index of the selected action?

```
// Create a new Alert Controller
actionSheetAlert = 
    UIAlertController.Create ("", "SELECT YEAR", UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet);

try {

    for (int i = 0; i < years.Count; i++) {
        // Add Actions
        actionSheetAlert.AddAction (
            UIAlertAction.Create (years [i].ToString (), UIAlertActionStyle.Default, 
                (action) => {

                    string year = actionSheetAlert.Actions.ElementAt(i).ToString();

                    Console.WriteLine ("Selected year:" + year);

                    this.DismissViewController (true, null);
                }
        ));

    } 

} catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine (ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
}

actionSheetAlert.AddAction (
    UIAlertAction.Create ("Cancel", UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, 
        (action) => {

            this.DismissViewController (true, null);
        }
    ));

this.PresentViewController (actionSheetAlert, true, null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was quite simple.

Simply access the Title property of the action selected like this:

Change this

```
string year = actionSheetAlert.Actions.ElementAt(i).ToString();
```

To this

```
string year = action.Title;
```